# Android LVL and Google Apps account

Tags: android

Is it possible to use a Google Apps account as a test account with the Android License Verification Library?

I've done some testing and even though I have my Google Apps account listed, I always get back an unlicensed response.  The only account I've ever had success testing with is one ending in @gmail.com

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

As per the note on the publisher site:

http://market.android.com/publish/editProfile

> This response will be sent to devices
>   using xxxx@gmail.com or the Test
>   accounts listed above for applications
>   you have uploaded to Market.
>   Additionally, this account **(but not
>   the Test accounts)** will receive this
>   response for applications that have
>   not yet been uploaded to Market.

xxxx@gmail.com being the signin email for the publisher account.

If you take a look at the dev guides:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#test-env

Point two maybe the solution to your troubles:

> An optional set of test accounts that
>   will receive the static test response
>   when they check the license of an
>   application that you have uploaded
>   **(regardless whether the application is
>   published or not).**

Comment: Yes, I've read those docs.  Here's the confusing/incorrect part in the documentation: "You can use any Google account as a test account. If you want to own and control the test accounts, you can create the accounts yourself and distribute the credentials to your developers or testers."  Google accounts don't have to end in @gmail and my Apps account is also a Google account.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is then. I have an application in testing - it is saved, but not published in my publisher acount. One of the testers testing my app is dom@hisdomain.com [his google acount login] (there are three testers, so the list is: one@gmail.com, dom@hisdomain.com, three@gmail.com). All of the acounts above receive the selected test respone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Google app account for LVL testing. As you mentioned, the Google app account (usually) wont end up with 'gmail.com'. That is perfectly fine. 
I use google app account as my publisher account in market and gmail account as test account. The response is inline with Table 1 in this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#test-acct-setup